# How to match app_instance_id and client_id in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics-firebase, measurement-protocol

I have a mobile app (ios,android) and a website not directly related to the app where users make purchases.

Some user events are sent to firebase via the application sdk, but some must be sent from your own backend, which receives data about user actions (purchasing or subscription, for example) on the site.

I found out that it is possible to use the measurement protocol and send events from the application using the app_instance_id and use the client_id to send events from the web.
At first glance, it seems that the user who bought something on the site is not connected in any way with the user in the application and it is not clear how to connect the activity on the site with a specific user in the application. At the backend level, this can be done through the mail/login specified by the user, but it is not at all clear how to pass through the open protocol for the user in one case the app_instance_id, and in the other client_id so that they match as one user.

Does anyone know how firebase matches the app_instance_id and client_id of the same person and what needs to be done to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: You might need to store app_instance_id in your backend too.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how firebase matches the app_instance_id and client_id of the same person and what needs to be done to achieve this?

You would need to set the user ID as well, in each environment. Ensure it's something opaque and does not reveal any PII.